# One line with several variables in bash

Tags: bash

I want to be able to define variables on one line like this:

```
variable=text1|text2|text3
```

instead of

```
variable1=text1
variable2=text2
variable3=text3
```

How would I accomplish this easily and then still be able to call them separately in an easy way? Preferably by calling them with $variable[1] for text2.

The values does not really have to be separated by a pipe, that is just for example.

I',m not really a coder, I just dabble in some scripting on my Ubuntu based HTPC, so please be gentle ;)

EDIT: Thank you DevSolar for leading me on the right track. I wanted an array, but with another delimiter than space and now I solved it like this:

```
variable="text1;text2;text3"

IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< "$variable"

echo "${array[0]}"
echo "${array[1]}"
echo "${array[2]}"
```

Just realized that a pipe might not have been the best delimiter so I went with semicolon instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is an [array](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)?

```
array=(text1 text2 text3)
echo ${array[0]}
```

Will give `text1`.

Comment: Thanks for leading me on the right track. See my updated post about my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although array might be the preferred way, an alternative for assigning multiple values at once

```
$ read var1 var2 var3 <<< "val1 val2 val3"; echo $var1
val1
```

Comment: While `read` has its very good uses, this is not one of them. `var1="val1" var2="val2" var3="val3"` (all on one line, yes) is legal, shorter, and easier to read (and not subject to the current value of `IFS`).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a string like

```
data="text 1|text 2|text3"
```

then using `read` to populate an array is useful:

```
$ IFS="|" read -ra var <<< "$data"
$ echo "${var[0]}"
text 1
$ echo "${var[1]}"
text 2
$ echo "${var[2]}"
text3
```

Otherwise, direct array assignment is possible:

```
var=("text 1" "text 2" text3)
```